# Plural or singular after "what .... is / are + plural noun"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-pronouns

Example: "what the researchers are looking for is / are materials that ..."

Comment: Yes, that is a good question. :) -- "[What the researchers are looking for] **is/are** [materials that . . .]". Hopefully someone soon will provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

*What* (s) and *what* (pl) are obviously  not inflected, so you have to infer which one it is.  The word is referring to *materials*, so select the of the noun there.  Examples:  What materials are there?  What material is there?